# function without args that uses elements precreated

Tags: python, function, python-2.7

I'm making a program that uses a variable called "lev" that must be used in all my functions, but it doesn't need to be an argument of the function. I mean, the function makes some things and then changes "lev" value, so I need something like this:

```
>>> lev=8
>>> def t():
>>>      print 1+1
>>>      lev = lev+1
>>> t()
>>> lev
9
```

That was my first idea, but in practice, doing this, doesn't work.

I can't use "return" to get the new "lev" variable, because there are functions that I need to return a True or False from them AND edits the value of "lev" too, so I can't use the "return" command. Someone has an idea? Thanks

Comment: That's what functions are all about, they have their own scope.

Comment: Plus the code that you're saying that actually works is not possible. `lev` is a local variable for the function hence it will fail with `UnBoundLocalError`.

Comment: there is always a better solution than using global variables. Python functions can return more than one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define it `global lev` in the function ...

```
>>> lev=8
>>> def t():
>>>      global lev
>>>      print 1+1
>>>      lev = lev+1
>>> t()
>>> lev
9
```